# Ubuntu user not able to open port to listen to IP V6 addresses

Tags: node.js, linux, ubuntu, listener, ipv6

I am having one Nodejs application which will listen on IPV6 addresses. But when I am running it via a normal user it is not running. But when I run it with Sudo it is running and listening on 80 port. It seems my normal user is not able to open a port for IPV6 addresses listening. Please help.

**Application:**

```
$ cat app2
#!/bin/bash
SCRIPT=$(readlink -f "$0")
SCRIPTPATH=$(dirname "$SCRIPT")

node $SCRIPTPATH/lib/app2.js


$cat app2.js
   

const hn="::",s=require("http").createServer((e,t)=>{t.statusCode=200,t.setHeader("Content- 
Type","text/html"),t.end("<htm><body><h1>Hello World</h1></body> 
</html>")});
s.listen(0x50,hn,_=>console.log("Server is running")); 
process.on('uncaughtException',_=>{console.log("Error")});
```

**With normal user it gives an error.**

```
$ ./app2
Error
```

With Sudo privilege, it is running

```
$ sudo ./app2
Server is running
```

It is listening on port 80 for IPV6

```
$ sudo lsof -i -P -n | grep LISTEN

systemd-r  533 systemd-resolve   13u  IPv4  18587      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.53:53 (LISTEN)
sshd       689            root    3u  IPv4 110220      0t0  TCP *:22 (LISTEN)
sshd       689            root    4u  IPv6 110222      0t0  TCP *:22 (LISTEN)
node      8034            root   18u  IPv6 134249      0t0  TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
```

It is an Ubuntu machine.

```
$ cat /etc/*release

DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=20.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=focal
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS"
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="20.04.2 LTS (Focal Fossa)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS"
VERSION_ID="20.04"
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
VERSION_CODENAME=focal
UBUNTU_CODENAME=focal
```

Comment: It is a security limitation enforced by the OS.  A non-privilege user cannot bind on ports below 1024.  Therefore, you **have** to use `sudo` to bind to port 80, it is normal.

Comment: Thanks  for helping